# Bijection between subgroups $X$ satisfying $U\leq X\leq G$ and $U$-invariant subgroups $Y$ satisfying $U\cap N\leq Y\leq N$.

Tags: group-theory

Hi: this problem is from Kurzweil and Stellmacher, The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction, page 20:

[image: Image_1]

The homomorphism theorem gives a bijection between subgroups of the image and subgroups of the domain containiing the kernel. Don't know if this can be useful. On the other hand, by the 2nd isomorphism theorem, $G/N \cong U/U\cap N$. Again, I don't know if this is of any help. I need a function from $G$ to $N$ and then see if the image of $X$ is a $U$-invariant subgroup satisfying the second inequalities. But how  do I find such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take any subgroup $X$ of $G$ containing $U$ then it is equal to the product $U(X\cap N)$. That subgroup $X\cap N$ is your $Y$. It is clearly $U$-invariant since $U\subset X$ and $N$ is normal. Also clearly different $X$ correspond to different $Y$ and each $U$-invariant $Y$ between $U\cap N$ and $N$ corresponds to $X=UY$.

**To summarize:** The map $X\to X\cap N$ is a map from the set of all subgroups $X\ge U$ and all subgroups between $U\cap N$ and $N$ normalized by $U$. The inverse map is $Y\to YU$. Indeed, if we denote $X=YU$, then $X$ is always $\ge U$, and $X\cap N=Y(U\cap N)$ by the Dedekind (modular) law $=Y$ because $Y\ge U\cap N$.

QED

Comment: Thanks JCAA. Yes, the first statement by Dedekind's identity. There are two things I don't understand:

Comment: Thanks JCAA. Yes, the first statement by Dedekind's identity. There are two things I don't understand: (a) The bijection, let's call it $f$, is intersection with $N$. I don't understand why $f(X_1)=f(X_2)$ implies $X_1=X_2$, that is why $X_1\cap N=X_2\cap N$ implies $X_1=X_2$                                                                                                           (b) You say $f(UY)= Y$, for given $Y$. I don't see how!

Comment: I added a summary to my answer addressing, I believe, your questions.

Comment: I see. And what about the map being injective?

Comment: Injectivity comes from the fact that you have an inverse map $Y \mapsto YU$.

Comment: If a map has an inverse, it must be surjective and injective. Any other objections?

Comment: Ahhh! Really I considered intersection with N and in this way U is sent to $U\cap N$ and G is sent to N. But I don't know how I didn't realize $X\cap N$ was the Y I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should accept the answer if you think it is what you need.